# NLB support for IP based Loadbalancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, nlb

Does AWS NLB has any support for source IP based Loadbalancing?

Ex: say if IP range is 34.5.5.5-34.5.5.254 forward traffic to instance X?

Or if Traffic is from 34.6.6.6 forward to instance Y

Is there anyway to achieve this in AWS NLB?